# Delete Button didn't work

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

TIA.I have two buttons one is `Next(#next)` which post the `id(PRIMARY/AI)` one at a time from database in a `commentbox` (already working). and the `Processed(#processed)` which or must delete the row (the id shown in `commentbox`)from the database every time it clicks. I have the code : and really sorry if its not good, I'm using Ajax too:

PS: the codes is compilation of many tutorials 
PS: the processed button (delete) is the only problem here

This the JS:

```
<script>
    //jQuery code here!
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 0;
        $("#next").click(function() {
        commentCount += 1;
            $("#comments").load("load-comments.php", {
                commentNewCount: commentCount
            });
               $("#processed").removeAttr('disabled');
               $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
        $("#processed").click(function() {
            var element = $("#comments");
            var commentNewCount = element.attr("commentCount");
            var info = 'commentCount=' +commentNewCount;
            // alert(info);
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: 'deleteuser.php',
                      type: 'post',
                      data: info, 
                      success: function(){
                      }
                  });

                  $("#comments").parent().parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
                  $("#comments").remove();
                  });

            }
            return false;
               });
         $("#next").removeAttr('disabled');
         $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
</script>
```

phpcode in Next button:

```
 <?php
    include 'dbh.php';

    $commentNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 1 OFFSET $commentNewCount";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['id'];

        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no queue!";
    }

?>
```

phpcode in Processed button:

```
    <?php
include 'dbh.php';

$userid =$_POST['id'];

$delete = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=$commentNewCount");
if(!$delete){
echo "The queue Are already Delete" ;
}else{
echo "Success";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you misspelled your connection variable in the php code for the processed button. It should be `$conn`.

Comment: @fab thanks but actually the whole page was deleted here.I forgot to tell , I just only need to delete the id the shows in the commentbox

Comment: you're using the wrong variable in the DELETE's WHERE clause, far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In the frontend, you're using

```
var info = 'commentCount=' +commentNewCount;
```

while in PHP code you're not getting it, you should use

```
$commentNewCount =$_POST['commentCount'];
```

in the PHP deletion code, there is no 'id' POST value

also, pay attention to variable names, it's not clear if you're deleting a comment or a user

Comment: Im deleting the comment , but the problem the entire page was deleted . even the button. what I mean is when I click the button the whole page became blank.